# Setting properties inside class that is definied inside antoher class

Tags: c#, class, oop, properties

I have this piece of code:

```
class MyClass
{

    public class MySubClass
            {
                public int One {  private set; public get; }
                public int Two { private set; public get; }
                public int Three { private set; public get; }
            };
    public MySubClass ObjectMySubClass { private set; public get; }

    private void SetSomething()
    {
        ObjectMySubClass.One = 5; //can do that
    }

}
```

How i can make that my One, Two and Three variables can be read outside class but setted just in MyClass?

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
obj.ObjectMySubClass.One = 5; //can't
int value = obj.ObjectMySubClass.One; //can do that
```

Comment: You have a nested class, not a sub class?

Comment: The way to prevent that accessibility is : don't make it a nested type. The other approach is: electively *don't do that* (i.e. don't access the value if you feel you shouldn't).

Comment: I just copied your code into a project and it throws a compiler error for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think you can do it using just access modifiers. You can add additional interface just readonly properties and hide `MySubClass` to be private:

```
class MyClass
{
    public interface IMySubClass
    {
        int One { get; }
        int Two { get; }
        int Three { get; }
    }

    private class MySubClass : IMySubClass
    {
        public int One { set; get; }
        public int Two { set; get; }
        public int Three { set; get; }
    };

    private MySubClass _objectMySubClass;
    public IMySubClass ObjectMySubClass
    {
        get { return _objectMySubClass; }
    }

    private void SetSomething()
    {
        _objectMySubClass.One = 5; //can do that
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is Use Constructors:

```
class MyClass
{

public class MySubClass
{
    public int One { private set; get; }
    public int Two { private set; get; }
    public int Three { private set; get; }

    public MySubClass(int one, int two, int three)
    {
        this.One = one;
        this.Two = two;
        this.Three = three;
    }

};

public MySubClass ObjectMySubClass { private set; get; }

private void SetSomething()
{
    this.ObjectMySubClass = new MySubClass(1, 2, 3);
}
}
```

Then:

```
        MyClass obj = new MyClass();
        //obj.ObjectMySubClass.One = 5; //can't
        //obj.ObjectMySubClass = new MyClass.MySubClass(1, 2, 3); //can't
        int value = obj.ObjectMySubClass.One; //can do that
```